# How do I instantiate a rectangular array with data in it?

Tags: f#

I am trying to solve [Project Euler Problem #11](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11) using F#, and I am having issues figuring out how to instantiate the original grid.

I've tried:

```
let grid : int [,] = [|[|08; 02; 22; 97; 38; 15; 00; 40; 00; 75; 04; 05; 07; 78; 52; 12; 50; 77; 91; 08|]
                        [|49; 49; 99; 40; 17; 81; 18; 57; 60; 87; 17; 40; 98; 43; 69; 48; 04; 56; 62; 00|]
                        [|81; 49; 31; 73; 55; 79; 14; 29; 93; 71; 40; 67; 53; 88; 30; 03; 49; 13; 36; 65|]
                        [|52; 70; 95; 23; 04; 60; 11; 42; 69; 24; 68; 56; 01; 32; 56; 71; 37; 02; 36; 91|]
                        [|22; 31; 16; 71; 51; 67; 63; 89; 41; 92; 36; 54; 22; 40; 40; 28; 66; 33; 13; 80|]
                        [|24; 47; 32; 60; 99; 03; 45; 02; 44; 75; 33; 53; 78; 36; 84; 20; 35; 17; 12; 50|]
                        [|32; 98; 81; 28; 64; 23; 67; 10; 26; 38; 40; 67; 59; 54; 70; 66; 18; 38; 64; 70|]
                        [|67; 26; 20; 68; 02; 62; 12; 20; 95; 63; 94; 39; 63; 08; 40; 91; 66; 49; 94; 21|]
                        [|24; 55; 58; 05; 66; 73; 99; 26; 97; 17; 78; 78; 96; 83; 14; 88; 34; 89; 63; 72|]
                        [|21; 36; 23; 09; 75; 00; 76; 44; 20; 45; 35; 14; 00; 61; 33; 97; 34; 31; 33; 95|]
                        [|78; 17; 53; 28; 22; 75; 31; 67; 15; 94; 03; 80; 04; 62; 16; 14; 09; 53; 56; 92|]
                        [|16; 39; 05; 42; 96; 35; 31; 47; 55; 58; 88; 24; 00; 17; 54; 24; 36; 29; 85; 57|]
                        [|86; 56; 00; 48; 35; 71; 89; 07; 05; 44; 44; 37; 44; 60; 21; 58; 51; 54; 17; 58|]
                        [|19; 80; 81; 68; 05; 94; 47; 69; 28; 73; 92; 13; 86; 52; 17; 77; 04; 89; 55; 40|]
                        [|04; 52; 08; 83; 97; 35; 99; 16; 07; 97; 57; 32; 16; 26; 26; 79; 33; 27; 98; 66|]
                        [|88; 36; 68; 87; 57; 62; 20; 72; 03; 46; 33; 67; 46; 55; 12; 32; 63; 93; 53; 69|]
                        [|04; 42; 16; 73; 38; 25; 39; 11; 24; 94; 72; 18; 08; 46; 29; 32; 40; 62; 76; 36|]
                        [|20; 69; 36; 41; 72; 30; 23; 88; 34; 62; 99; 69; 82; 67; 59; 85; 74; 04; 36; 16|]
                        [|20; 73; 35; 29; 78; 31; 90; 01; 74; 31; 49; 71; 48; 86; 81; 16; 23; 57; 05; 54|]
                        [|01; 70; 54; 71; 83; 51; 54; 69; 16; 92; 33; 48; 61; 43; 52; 01; 89; 19; 67; 48|]|]
```

and many other permutations with no luck.  All my attempts give me:

> This expression was expected to have type `int [,]` but here has type `'a[]`

How do I instantiate the rectangular array without having to set each cell individually?

Comment: There's no syntax for a multidimensional array literal. Use `array2D` operator or `Array2D.init` function. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx) article.

Comment: You are creating a `int [] []` which might be okay for what you want - the access in `grid.[x].[y]` which might be awkward though

Comment: Instead of hardcoding data into the code I'd go with a text file and data loader function.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a built-in library function `array2D`. It converts array of arrays `int[][]` into a two-dimensional array `int[,]`. You can call it like this (using a slightly smaller input array):

```
let grid = 
  array2D [| [|08; 02; 22; |]
             [|49; 49; 99; |]         
             [|01; 70; 54; |] |]
```

or you can use the pipelining operator and call it like this:

```
let grid = 
  [| [|08; 02; 22; |]
     [|49; 49; 99; |]         
     [|01; 70; 54; |] |] |> array2D
```

While this is not a special language syntax for building 2D arrays, it practically functions as one.- F# has a number of similar functions that you can use to construct sets, immutable maps and other types. In the following example, `seq` and `dict` are all functions, but you can see them as syntax (for some other data types, there are longer functions like `Map.ofSeq`):

```
dict [ "cz", "Ahoj"; "en", "Hello" ]
seq { 1 .. 100 }
```

The function will actually work on any collection of collections (not just array of arrays), because it has the following type:

```
val array2D : seq<#seq<'a>> -> 'a[,]
```

This means that it takes any sequence (the outer `seq`) of any types that implement the `IEnumerable` interface (the inner `#seq`) - so you can also produce the data using more complex sequence comprehensions and then pass it to `array2D`.

Comment: Where does `map` come from? It doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe it requires some `open`s?

Comment: Map is the standard immutable associative array (or dictionary in c#) in f#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353686.aspx

Comment: @svick My bad - `map` does not actually exist. To construct map, one has to use the long function name - `Map.ofSeq`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
let my2DArray = 
    [| for i in 0 .. rowCount - 1 do 
        yield [| for i in 0 ..columnCount - 1 do yield init |] 
    |] |> array2D
```